# CFA in Lavaan is not setting factor loading to 1

Tags: r, r-lavaan

****I am running a CFA in R using the Lavaan pkg for the first time. I have got everything up and running however for some reason my none of my factor loadings are set to 1 like they are supposed to be. I want to know why Lavaan isn't automatically setting one of the loadings to one for each of the factors.

This is the code I used:****

```
    model1<-'comm=~relimport+relthink+relhurt
    Ind=~attend+prayer+relread
    relimport~~relthink'
  
    fit1 <-cfa(model1, data=SIM1, std.lv=TRUE)
    summary (fit1, ci=T, standardized=T, fit.measures=T )
    modindices(fit1, minimum.value=10, sort=TRUE)
    lavaanPlot(model=fit1, node_options=list(shape="box", fontname= "Helvetica"),
           edge_options=list(color="grey"), coefs=TRUE, stand=TRUE)
```

Here is my output:

```
    lavaan 0.6.13 ended normally after 30 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        14

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                           796        1769

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 2.707
  Degrees of freedom                                 7
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.911

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                              1394.558
  Degrees of freedom                                15
  P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.007

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)              -7374.779
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)      -7373.425
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                               14777.558
  Bayesian (BIC)                             14843.072
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)      14798.615

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.017
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    1.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.008

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv
  comm =~                                                                        
    relimport         0.796    0.050   15.875    0.000    0.698    0.894    0.796
    relthink          0.735    0.062   11.784    0.000    0.613    0.857    0.735
    relhurt           0.660    0.061   10.827    0.000    0.540    0.779    0.660
  Ind =~                                                                         
    attend            0.685    0.048   14.408    0.000    0.591    0.778    0.685
    prayer            1.605    0.065   24.794    0.000    1.478    1.732    1.605
    relread           1.134    0.052   21.960    0.000    1.033    1.235    1.134
  Std.all
         
    0.926
    0.672
    0.455
         
    0.523
    0.844
    0.757

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv
 .relimport ~~                                                                   
   .relthink         -0.007    0.069   -0.104    0.917   -0.143    0.129   -0.007
  comm ~~                                                                        
    Ind               0.609    0.043   14.108    0.000    0.525    0.694    0.609
  Std.all
         
   -0.027
         
    0.609

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv
   .relimport         0.106    0.071    1.489    0.137   -0.033    0.245    0.106
   .relthink          0.658    0.084    7.874    0.000    0.494    0.822    0.658
   .relhurt           1.668    0.097   17.268    0.000    1.479    1.857    1.668
   .attend            1.242    0.068   18.253    0.000    1.109    1.376    1.242
   .prayer            1.040    0.125    8.286    0.000    0.794    1.286    1.040
   .relread           0.955    0.075   12.676    0.000    0.807    1.103    0.955
    comm              1.000                               1.000    1.000    1.000
    Ind               1.000                               1.000    1.000    1.000
  Std.all
    0.143
    0.549
    0.793
    0.726
    0.288
    0.426
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that `std.lv=TRUE` was literally telling R-Lavaan not to set the first factor to one. So problem fixed!